# Alias method chain undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason my alias_method_chain doesn't want to work and I have no idea why. Can anyone explain to me why the following won't work?

```
[2] pry(main)> Client.respond_to? :mapping
=> true
[3] pry(main)> Client.alias_method_chain :mapping, :safety
NameError: undefined method `mapping' for class `Client'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get alias method chain for object of some class you should call `alias_method_chain` on class itself and not on its instance. If you want to make chain of class methods the same rule applies: you should call `alias_method_chain` on class's singleton class that can be obtained like that:

```
klass = class << Client; self; end  # => returns singleton class for Client class
```

In that case `Client` is an instance of `klass` class (that has `Class` class as its superclass).

Resulting example of class methods chain can be the following:

```
class Client
  def self.mapping
    puts 'mapping'
  end

  def self.mapping_with_safety
    puts 'safety'
    mapping_without_safety
  end

  class << self
    # call alias_method_chain in context of Client's singleton class
    alias_method_chain :mapping, :safety
  end
end

# alternatively you can do it outside of Client class like that 
# (class << Client; self; end).alias_method_chain :mapping, :safety

Client.mapping
# => safety
# => mapping
```

Comment: I found this out after the fact but for anyone else that finds this, this is the correct answer.

Another way of doing it would be with Client.class_eval {}

Answer (score 3):

In order for `alias_method_chain` to work, the mapping function must be an instance method, not a class method like in your example, so `Client.new.respond_to? :mapping` needs to be true (notice the new call).

Comment: (You can also check if the instance methods exists by calling Client.method_defined? "mapping", just saying)